# vagrant up fails of puphpet generated box

Tags: vagrant, hhvm, puphpet

I just created a very simple config with puphpet. It includes an nginx and a hhvm and a mysql. Nothing else yet. 
When I start to run vagrant up it fails  with the same message every time.

Here is the output:

```
vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Importing base box 'puphpet/ubuntu1404-x64'...
==> default: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
==> default: Checking if box 'puphpet/ubuntu1404-x64' is up to date...
==> default: Setting the name of the VM: vagrant-hhvm_default_1441131243385_35080
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
    default: Adapter 2: hostonly
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 22 => 6632 (adapter 1)
    default: 22 => 2222 (adapter 1)
==> default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default:
    default: Vagrant insecure key detected. Vagrant will automatically replace
    default: this with a newly generated keypair for better security.
    default:
    default: Inserting generated public key within guest...
    default: Removing insecure key from the guest if its present...
    default: Key inserted! Disconnecting and reconnecting using new SSH key...
==> default: Machine booted and ready!
==> default: Checking for guest additions in VM...
==> default: Checking for host entries
==> default: adding to (/etc/hosts) : 192.168.56.101  local.puphpet  # VAGRANT: 88884799495109854333bebc73976cae (default) / b08f4c50-86e3-4307-94f2-0175fcee553e
==> default: Setting hostname...
==> default: Configuring and enabling network interfaces...
==> default: Installing NFS client...
==> default: Exporting NFS shared folders...
==> default: Preparing to edit /etc/exports. Administrator privileges will be required...
The nfsd service does not appear to be running.
Starting the nfsd service
==> default: Mounting NFS shared folders...
==> default: Mounting shared folders...
    default: /vagrant => /Users/emul/vagrant-hhvm
    default: /tmp/vagrant-puppet/modules-118aff3d1d14e37133864c5b11fbc99f => /Users/emul/vagrant-hhvm/puphpet/puppet/modules
    default: /tmp/vagrant-puppet/manifests-893fcda21077f5a583c2dbbba8515c0a => /Users/emul/vagrant-hhvm/puphpet/puppet
==> default: Running provisioner: shell...
    default: Running: inline script
==> default: stdin: is not a tty
==> default: Running provisioner: shell...
    default: Running: /var/folders/s9/n6ctw0bs41gdk8qwd9_gv0dh0000gn/T/vagrant-shell20150901-17569-996glt.sh
==> default: stdin: is not a tty
==> default:
==> default:  ____        ____  _   _ ____      _      generated using
==> default: |  _ \ _   _|  _ \| | | |  _ \ ___| |_   ___ ___  _ __ ___
==> default: | |_) | | | | |_) | |_| | |_) / _ \ __| / __/ _ \| '_ ` _ \
==> default: |  __/| |_| |  __/|  _  |  __/  __/ |_ | (_| (_) | | | | | |
==> default: |_|    \__,_|_|   |_| |_|_|   \___|\__(_)___\___/|_| |_| |_|
==> default: Running initial-setup apt-get update
==> default: Finished running initial-setup apt-get update
==> default: Running provisioner: shell...
    default: Running: /var/folders/s9/n6ctw0bs41gdk8qwd9_gv0dh0000gn/T/vagrant-shell20150901-17569-1uw0u3y.sh
==> default: stdin: is not a tty
==> default: Generating public/private rsa key pair.
==> default: Your identification has been saved in /vagrant/puphpet/files/dot/ssh/root_id_rsa.
==> default: Your public key has been saved in /vagrant/puphpet/files/dot/ssh/root_id_rsa.pub.
==> default: The key fingerprint is:
==> default: 43:bc:72:31:8c:6a:dc:cb:df:e4:4a:7f:38:a9:a5:a5 root@local
==> default: The key's randomart image is:
==> default: +--[ RSA 2048]----+
==> default: |                 |
==> default: |       +         |
==> default: |      . *        |
==> default: |   . o . +       |
==> default: |    + o S        |
==> default: |   . . + .       |
==> default: |      o . +o     |
==> default: |       o X+ .    |
==> default: |        Eo+o     |
==> default: +-----------------+
==> default: dpkg-preconfigure: unable to re-open stdin: No such file or directory
==> default: Your private key for SSH-based authentication has been saved to 'puphpet/files/dot/ssh/root_id_rsa'!
==> default: Generating public/private rsa key pair.
==> default: Your identification has been saved in /vagrant/puphpet/files/dot/ssh/id_rsa.
==> default: Your public key has been saved in /vagrant/puphpet/files/dot/ssh/id_rsa.pub.
==> default: The key fingerprint is:
==> default: a8:6b:13:2c:9b:02:37:05:ec:61:2e:dc:ca:2c:ef:9a root@local
==> default: The key's randomart image is:
==> default: +--[ RSA 2048]----+
==> default: | .               |
==> default: |  =              |
==> default: |.+.o             |
==> default: |..o..  .         |
==> default: |o..o  . S        |
==> default: |o++ o.           |
==> default: |oo =..           |
==> default: |..+ o.           |
==> default: |E+....           |
==> default: +-----------------+
==> default: Your private key for SSH-based authentication has been saved to 'puphpet/files/dot/ssh/id_rsa'!
==> default: Adding generated root key to /root/.ssh/id_rsa
==> default: Adding generated root key to /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
==> default: Adding generated root key to /root/.ssh/authorized_keys
==> default: Adding generated key to /home/vagrant/.ssh/id_rsa
==> default: Adding generated key to /home/vagrant/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
==> default: Adding generated key to /home/vagrant/.ssh/authorized_keys
==> default: Running provisioner: shell...
    default: Running: /var/folders/s9/n6ctw0bs41gdk8qwd9_gv0dh0000gn/T/vagrant-shell20150901-17569-18e0m4w.sh
==> default: stdin: is not a tty
==> default: Running provisioner: shell...
    default: Running: /var/folders/s9/n6ctw0bs41gdk8qwd9_gv0dh0000gn/T/vagrant-shell20150901-17569-gk5ewj.sh
==> default: stdin: is not a tty
==> default: Running provisioner: shell...
    default: Running: /var/folders/s9/n6ctw0bs41gdk8qwd9_gv0dh0000gn/T/vagrant-shell20150901-17569-14ore9c.sh
==> default: stdin: is not a tty
==> default: Successfully installed deep_merge-1.0.1
==> default: 1 gem installed
==> default: Successfully installed thread_safe-0.3.5
==> default: Successfully installed minitest-5.8.0
==> default: Successfully installed tzinfo-1.2.2
==> default: Successfully installed i18n-0.7.0
==> default: Successfully installed activesupport-4.2.4
==> default: 5 gems installed
==> default: Successfully installed vine-0.2
==> default: 1 gem installed
==> default: Running provisioner: puppet...
==> default: Running Puppet with site.pp...
==> default: stdin: is not a tty
==> default: Info: Loading facts in /tmp/vagrant-puppet/modules-118aff3d1d14e37133864c5b11fbc99f/apt/lib/facter/apt_update_last_success.rb
==> default: Info: Loading facts in /tmp/vagrant-puppet/modules-118aff3d1d14e37133864c5b11fbc99f/apt/lib/facter/apt_updates.rb
==> default: Info: Loading facts in /tmp/vagrant-puppet/modules-118aff3d1d14e37133864c5b11fbc99f/composer/lib/facter/composer_home.rb
==> default: Info: Loading facts in /tmp/vagrant-puppet/modules-118aff3d1d14e37133864c5b11fbc99f/concat/lib/facter/concat_basedir.rb
==> default: Info: Loading facts in /tmp/vagrant-puppet/modules-118aff3d1d14e37133864c5b11fbc99f/firewall/lib/facter/ip6tables_version.rb
==> default: Info: Loading facts in /tmp/vagrant-puppet/modules-118aff3d1d14e37133864c5b11fbc99f/firewall/lib/facter/iptables_persistent_version.rb
==> default: Info: Loading facts in /tmp/vagrant-puppet/modules-118aff3d1d14e37133864c5b11fbc99f/firewall/lib/facter/iptables_version.rb
==> default: Info: Loading facts in /tmp/vagrant-puppet/modules-118aff3d1d14e37133864c5b11fbc99f/git/lib/facter/git_exec_path.rb
==> default: Info: Loading facts in /tmp/vagrant-puppet/modules-118aff3d1d14e37133864c5b11fbc99f/git/lib/facter/git_version.rb
==> default: Info: Loading facts in /tmp/vagrant-puppet/modules-118aff3d1d14e37133864c5b11fbc99f/java/lib/facter/java_major_version.rb
==> default: Info: Loading facts in /tmp/vagrant-puppet/modules-118aff3d1d14e37133864c5b11fbc99f/java/lib/facter/java_patch_level.rb
==> default: Info: Loading facts in /tmp/vagrant-puppet/modules-118aff3d1d14e37133864c5b11fbc99f/java/lib/facter/java_version.rb
==> default: Info: Loading facts in /tmp/vagrant-puppet/modules-118aff3d1d14e37133864c5b11fbc99f/php/lib/facter/php_fact_extension_dir.rb
==> default: Info: Loading facts in /tmp/vagrant-puppet/modules-118aff3d1d14e37133864c5b11fbc99f/php/lib/facter/php_fact_version.rb
==> default: Info: Loading facts in /tmp/vagrant-puppet/modules-118aff3d1d14e37133864c5b11fbc99f/puppi/lib/facter/last_run.rb
==> default: Info: Loading facts in /tmp/vagrant-puppet/modules-118aff3d1d14e37133864c5b11fbc99f/puppi/lib/facter/puppi_projects.rb
==> default: Info: Loading facts in /tmp/vagrant-puppet/modules-118aff3d1d14e37133864c5b11fbc99f/puppi/lib/facter/windows_common_appdata.rb
==> default: Info: Loading facts in /tmp/vagrant-puppet/modules-118aff3d1d14e37133864c5b11fbc99f/rvm/lib/facter/rvm_installed.rb
==> default: Info: Loading facts in /tmp/vagrant-puppet/modules-118aff3d1d14e37133864c5b11fbc99f/rvm/lib/facter/rvm_version.rb
==> default: Info: Loading facts in /tmp/vagrant-puppet/modules-118aff3d1d14e37133864c5b11fbc99f/staging/lib/facter/staging_http_get.rb
==> default: Info: Loading facts in /tmp/vagrant-puppet/modules-118aff3d1d14e37133864c5b11fbc99f/staging/lib/facter/staging_windir.rb
==> default: Info: Loading facts in /tmp/vagrant-puppet/modules-118aff3d1d14e37133864c5b11fbc99f/stdlib/lib/facter/facter_dot_d.rb
==> default: Info: Loading facts in /tmp/vagrant-puppet/modules-118aff3d1d14e37133864c5b11fbc99f/stdlib/lib/facter/pe_version.rb
==> default: Info: Loading facts in /tmp/vagrant-puppet/modules-118aff3d1d14e37133864c5b11fbc99f/stdlib/lib/facter/puppet_vardir.rb
==> default: Info: Loading facts in /tmp/vagrant-puppet/modules-118aff3d1d14e37133864c5b11fbc99f/stdlib/lib/facter/root_home.rb
==> default: Error: "off" is not a boolean.  It looks to be a String at /tmp/vagrant-puppet/modules-118aff3d1d14e37133864c5b11fbc99f/nginx/manifests/resource/location.pp:198 on node local.puphpet
==> default: Error: "off" is not a boolean.  It looks to be a String at /tmp/vagrant-puppet/modules-118aff3d1d14e37133864c5b11fbc99f/nginx/manifests/resource/location.pp:198 on node local.puphpet
The SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status. Vagrant
assumes that this means the command failed. The output for this command
should be in the log above. Please read the output to determine what
went wrong.
```

The VM is running but nothing is available on it (nginx, hhvm). I don't know if it matters but I'm running it on MacOS X 10.10
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: seems there is an error at `==> default: Error: "off" is not a boolean.  It looks to be a String at /tmp/vagrant-puppet/modules-118aff3d1d14e37133864c5b11fbc99f/nginx/manifests/resource/location.pp:198 on node local.puphpet` so look the file *nginx/manifests/resource/location.pp* line 198 and replace "off" by "false"

Comment: The problem is that as I see it is declared as false.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your puphpet/config.yml file

Change all instances of:

```
autoindex: 'off'
internal: 'off'
```

to:

```
autoindex: false
internal: false
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. So it was a bug in puphpet indeed.

Comment: Has anyone reported this to PuPHPet yet?

Answer (score 0):

got the same problem at the moment, but there is no off in this line it's

```
198. validate_bool($internal)
```

this var is declared couple of lines above in

```
define nginx::resource::location (
  $ensure               = present,
  $internal             = false,
```

docu for this var is

[*internal*]             - Indicates whether or not this loation can be used for internal requests only. Default: false

so it seems like problem is somewhere else

and my setup is Win8 host, Vbox, Ubuntu Trusty 14.04 LTS x64, NFS, nginx, PHP 5.6, mysql 5.6